# How to connect a non-rooted Android phone to an ethernet LAN as a client

Tags: lan, ip-address, ethernet

How can I connect a non-rooted Android phone to an Ethernet LAN as a client and use it as a host?

I got a public static IP. It's in my optical fiber router and I can assign it to a LAN host of my choice.

Before answering, please read the following points:

1. I don't want to use the WiFi interface
2. I tried an USB-to-ethternet cable but that allows me to configure the phone as an Ethernet-to-LTE access point for the LAN attached hosts. It's a tethering service

**I want to use my phone as a power-frugal server with a public static IP address.**

Ciao

Comment: Public IPs don't appeart out of nowhere.So where should this public IP come from? A Ethernet adapter is just a piece of hardware and the used IP address has to match the network it is connected to, so a public IP has nothing to do with the adapter which makes it difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I'm paying for a public static IP. I got it. It's in my optical fiber router and I can assign it to a LAN host of my choice.